# Django cannot find project app - cannot import x_app

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, bitnami

I am working on moving a django project from a Windows environment to a Ubuntu environment. The project was stored in git and cloned into the Ubuntu environment. I am using virtualenv for a clean slate (same as on windows environment).

Whether I run `django-admin check` or anything using `python manage.py` I get the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bitnami/djangoenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 244, in create
    app_module = import_module(app_name)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'akita_app'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bitnami/djangoenv/bin/django-admin", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/home/bitnami/djangoenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/bitnami/djangoenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/bitnami/djangoenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/bitnami/djangoenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/bitnami/djangoenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 246, in create
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'akita_app'. Check that 'akitaapp.apps.AkitaAppConfig.name' is correct.
```

The `akita_app` or `akitaapp` (same thing) that is missing is the the **akitaapp** folder.
**Edit:** I should note that I realized my Windows environment was django 3.0.6 and my Ubuntu environment is 3.2.9.

The project works perfectly in the Windows environment so I am guessing something is not declared properly. I've tried messing with `PYTHONPATH` to no avail.

My project structure looks as below. Many thanks to any guidance that can be offered.

```
app/
├── akita_project
│   ├── akitaapp
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── genpedigree.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   ├── 0002_auto_20200610_2116.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── __pycache__
│   │   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │       ├── 0002_auto_20200610_2116.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │       └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── admin.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │   ├── apps.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │   ├── d_table.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │   ├── forms.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │   ├── genpedigree.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │   ├── models.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │   ├── urls.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │   └── views.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   └── main
│   │   │       └── css
│   │   │           ├──redacted
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   └── main
│   │   │       ├──redacted
│   │   ├── testdigree.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── akita_project
│   │   ├── asgi.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations.me
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │   ├── router.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │   ├── settings.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │   ├── urls.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── router.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── akita.sqlite3
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── desktop.ini
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   └── output_data.csv
└── requirements.txt
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    path("", include('akitaapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

**settings.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'xxx'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['x']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'materializecssform',
    'tinymce',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'akitaapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'akita_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'akita_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['akita_project.router.AkitaDbRouter']

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'akita_app': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'akita.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'height': 360,
    'width': 1120,
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 20,
    'selector': 'textarea',
    'theme': 'modern',
    'plugins': '''
            textcolor save link image media preview codesample contextmenu
            table code lists fullscreen  insertdatetime  nonbreaking
            contextmenu directionality searchreplace wordcount visualblocks
            visualchars code fullscreen autolink lists  charmap print  hr
            anchor pagebreak
            ''',
    'toolbar1': '''
            fullscreen preview bold italic underline | fontselect,
            fontsizeselect  | forecolor backcolor | alignleft alignright |
            aligncenter alignjustify | indent outdent | bullist numlist table |
            | link image media | codesample |
            ''',
    'toolbar2': '''
            visualblocks visualchars |
            charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor |  code |
            ''',
    'contextmenu': 'formats | link image',
    'menubar': True,
    'statusbar': True,
    }
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AkitaAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'akita_app'
```

Comment: can you please update your question with `setting.py` `urls.py` `views.py` file code ?

Comment: Placed the urls.py from akita_project, left out views.py as it is rather large and does not appear to contain much relevance

Comment: could you please share the `apps.py` code.

Comment: @ShreeyanshJain I've added apps.py. Also now using the same DJango version as before. 3.0.6. Same issues.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are using incorrect name in you `apps.py` file

`apps.py`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AkitaAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'akitaapp'
```